# Update/re-render Charts.js in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

Trying to re-render charts every time when i have some change in API, here is the method:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const data = changes['data'].currentValue;
    this.draw(data);
}
```

and draw function

```
private draw(charts) {
 this.charts = charts.map((chart, i) => {
    this.options.title.text = chart.title;
    const options = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chart,
        options: this.options
    };
    return new Chart(`chart${i}`, options);
 });
 this.charts.forEach(chart => {
    chart.update();
 });
}
```

you can see that i try to update/re-render charts in draw function. In console log i can see that chart object was updated with new data, but they just disappear from page. What's wrong in my update method?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reproduce it with jsfidlle, to debug it better :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i know it's a hack, but for the moment it's ok )))
So, basically i check if charts already exist in DOM, and if exist remove them and create new canvas elements.

```
private removeAction() {
  const block = document.querySelector('#chartsBlock');

   //remove
  while (block.firstChild) {
    block.removeChild(block.firstChild);
  }

   // create
  this.charts.forEach((chart, i) => {
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = `chart${i}`;
    block.appendChild(canvas);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef):

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private detector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const data = changes['data'].currentValue;
    this.draw(data);
    this.detector.detectChanges()
    // if detectChanges() doesn't work, try markForCheck()
}
```

Comment: Nice, but i don't think that the problem it's to detect changes in my case. I detect changes in ngOnChanges method. The problem is that after updating, charts stop to be visible. I did a hack for my problem, you can see below my comment

Comment: The problem is not detecting the change, the problem is that, the way Angular works, sometimes changes do net reflect on the page. Calling detectChanges() force Angular to re-render any changes that might not have been rendered.

Comment: Hmm, ok now i got your idea, let me try that